Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $H$ be a Hilbert space. On $\text{Irr}(A:H)$, is pointwise SOT topology finer than the hull-kernel topology?
Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $H$ be a Hilbert space. On $\text{Irr}(A:H)$, is pointwise SOT topology finer than the hull-kernel topology?
Here, $\text{Irr}(A:H)$ is the set of all irreducible representations of $A$ on $H$.

By definition of the hull-kernel topology, a net $(\pi_i)_{i \in I}$ converges to $\pi$ in the hull-kernel topology iff,
$$\forall \text{ subnet } I_0 \text{ of } I, \pi \in \overline{\{\pi_i: i \in I_0\}}^{\text{hull-kernel}}$$
iff,
$$\forall \text{ subnet } I_0 \text{ of } I, \bigcap_{i \in I_0} \ker(\pi_i) \subset \ker(\pi)$$
Now, assume $(\pi_i)_{i \in I} \to \pi$ in pointwise SOT, we need to show $(\pi_i)_{i \in I} \to \pi$ in the hull-kernel topology as well. Let $I_0$ be a subnet of $I$. Then $(\pi_i)_{i \in I_0} \to \pi$ pointwise SOT. Thus, for any $a \in \bigcap_{i \in I_0} \ker(\pi_i)$, we have,
$$0 = \pi_i(a) \to \pi(a) \text{ in SOT}$$
Hence, $\pi(a) = 0$. This shows $\bigcap_{i \in I_0} \ker(\pi_i) \subset \ker(\pi)$. By the equivalence we established before, we see that $(\pi_i)_{i \in I} \to \pi$ in the hull-kernel topology, so pointwise SOT is finer than the hull-kernel topology.
Remark: The proof actually shows that, for any Hausdorff topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathbb{B}(H)$, the pointwise-$\mathcal{T}$ topology on $\text{Irr}(A:H)$ is finer than the hull-kernel topology.
